# Make Xcode treat "may not respond to" as errors instead of warnings

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I know about the "treat warnings as errors" option in the build settings, but is there any way to set this for specific warnings only, or just for the "may not responds to selector X" ones?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, interesting, was Googling around and found this, if it helps - [Selectively disable GCC warnings for only part of a translation unit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965093/selectively-disable-gcc-warnings-for-only-part-of-a-translation-unit)

Comment: Heh not sure how i missed this one, thanks :) Any luck getting something out of it though?

Comment: Ah, haven't got around to trying it yet. Was something I was looking for too though, have to see if it works ..

Answer (score 1):

following the link that Tejaswi supplied, i added this to the file and it generated an error instead of a warning:

#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wobjc-method-access"

by the way, getting the warning string for any warning you see in xcode can be done by clicking "reveal in log" for the warning. at the end of the log line for the warning will be the warning string in brackets.