# How to disable all warnings in g++ on a few lines of code

Tags: g++, warnings, gcc-warning

How to disable all warnings on a few lines of code. 
Specific warnings can be disabled using GCC diagnostic feature, but is there a flag for all warnings.
I tried this way but it doesn't work

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-wall"
// some code
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/965093/469210 for details on the gcc diagnostic pragma which may help.

Answer (score 9):

From here: http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/SuppressingGCCWarnings.html

For version 4.6 or later, you can save the state of the user's diagnostic flags. You can insert this around the line that causes the spurious warning:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
    // Code that causes warning goes here
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

In order to achieve the desired behavior, you should use "-Wall" instead of "-Wdeprecated-declarations" (and not "-wall" -- note the upcase "W").

Comment: Using -Wall instead of a more specific tag does not work at all (at least with gcc >8 so I highly doubt it has ever worked), just leaving this here...

Answer (score 1):

I think gcc -w filename.c does so 
-w flag is to ignore warnings

Comment: -w flag will help if I want to disable warnings on a whole file, not on some part of it.

Comment: oh now i understood the question, will see n let you know if found any.

Comment: btw why do you need such functionality ?

Comment: When 3rd party headers are used, which contain a lot of warnings, but you don't have permission to change or fix them, you can include headers by surrounding them with "warning disable" code.