# Disabling warnings about Boost headers in XCode 4.1

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, xcode4

I am writing a C++ program that uses Boost, using XCode 4.1 as IDE and compiler front-end. I get quite a lot of warnings in various Boost headers, and I would like to disable all warnings for those headers (but still enable them for my own project). Is there an easy way to do so?

[image: Here's my search path settings]

Comment: Not in general for a specific header set and instantiations from them. But for the parts in your translation unite see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965093/selectively-disable-gcc-warnings-for-only-part-of-a-translation-unit).

Comment: @Georg: I had read that question, but 1. I'm not using GCC; 2. I don't wanna have to write multiple `#pragma` in each .cpp file, whenever I'm including a Boost header. I'd like a more general solution, if possible.

Comment: What compiler are you using then?

Comment: @Andrea: See [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#diagnostics_pragmas) for Clang. I'm afraid a general solution isn't really possible if you think of boost template instantiations in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a decent workaround, based on what @Georg Fritzsche suggested:
I have added the various incriminated boost headers to the .pch file (the pre-compiled header), and wrapped them around a `#pragma push` - `#pragma pop` block, like this:

```
// We do not want to have warnings about Boost headers!
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wconversion"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wshadow"

#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_types.hpp>
...
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

This works perfectly, and it's not as annoying as having to surround the boost headers with `#pragma` in each .cpp file, as I feared.

Comment: I have added a .pch file to my project and also enabled precompiled headers but my warnings are not gone. I have the same issue you had. Do I need to do something else ? I have included the headers file which gives warnings in the .pch file with no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, that I found to work in Xcode 5.x (yet it is expected to work with Xcode 4).
In the *Build Settings* of the Boost depending target, instead of setting the headers' path under `Header Search Paths`, I write it under `Other C++ Flags`, prefixed by `-isystem`

[image: snapshot of the other C++ flags]