# How to disable external warnings in Qt for Symbian?

Tags: c++, qt, symbian, qt-creator

**Short question:** Is there a gcce equivalent to `#pragma warning(push, 0)` and `#pragma warning(pop)`?

**Long question**: Is there a "neat" way to disable warnings in includes from Symbian SDKs when building Symbian projects in Qt Creator? Even a small hello world project results in lots of them, not to mention bigger, serious projects.

I've heard about patching SDKs and that's what I'm trying to avoid - that may be good for one-developer, one-SDK project, but in my case there is a team of developers, each coding for multiple Symbian platforms.

In desktop app we used to wrap includes of external headers in mentioned `#pragma warning(push, 0)` and `#pragma warning(pop)`, but I can't find anything simmilar to it in gcce.

Comment: See the answers [to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/965093/492336)