# Partially disable pedantic warnings in gcc within source

Tags: c, gcc, suppress-warnings

I am trying to get `gcc` to shut up about my usage of binary constants. They make the code more readable, but prevent me from using `-pedantic` which I comply with otherwise. I would either like to have a switch like `-fnobinaryconstwarn` or similar (which I don't think exists after perusing the man page for a while) or use a

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-pedantic"
```

to selectively disable the pedantic warnings for a short stretch like described here:
[Selectively disable GCC warnings for only part of a translation unit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965093/selectively-disable-gcc-warnings-for-only-part-of-a-translation-unit)
Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. 
What are my options?

For `clang`

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wpedantic"
```

works, while the line above doesn't, but it generates an error for `gcc`.

Comment: can you give an example of your "use of binary constants"?

Comment: Similar to these:

`unsigned int piece = 0b10010101;`

That feature was introduced in gcc-4.3.0. I actually think the problem is deeper though, since turning off the warnings introduced by `-pedantic` should be possible somehow, if that specific one doesn't have a flag.

Comment: gcc should be more modular on these things, have explicit warning flags for all its features and then the `-Wall`, `-pedantic` whatever flags should clearly list all the primitive ones from which they are composed. But this is probably wishful thinking.

Comment: GCC 4.8 will support `-Wpedantic` so the `#pragma` will work

Comment: @JensGustedt, that's how it works. When a warning is printed it tells you which `-Wxxx` option caused it. `-pedantic` is a single feature (diagnose non-standard extensions) so has a single flag.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, but it doesn't seem that all of these can be switched on or off via the pragma.

Comment: Almost all of them can. See my other comment about `-Wpedantic`. There's no point complaining about "wishful thinking" on SO, if it bothers you add a feature request to GCC's bugzilla, that's the way to get changes made. e.g. `-Wpedantic` was added because someone asked for it (and implemented it) not because someone somewhere wished for it.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, wow, looks as you felt insulted, wasn't my intention.  And for the extension in question, your statement is simply not true, for binary constants there is no `-Wsomething option` and the warning doesn't contain a hint how it could be switched off.

Comment: So file an enhancement request in [GCC's bugzilla](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/) for an option controlling the warning. Wishing doesn't get things done. Or for this specific case, until a specific flag is added don't use `-pedantic` if you want to use non-standard extensions.

Comment: If you were to turn that comment into an answer, then I'd accept it, since it seems the most appropriate response. Other than that, I am a little curious and trying to actually understand the reasoning. I compile with (among other flags) `--std=gnu99 -pedantic` and as far as I understand the C standard regarding constants, it's OK to parse extra sorts of constants, so issuing a diagnostic isn't required even by strict conformance standards. I can sort of see why one would want it to appear for `--std=c99` but not for the gnu variety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe, you could use a macro which can do what you want to achieve in a portable manner.
here's a short example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BINARY(N) strtol(#N, 0, 2)

int main()
{
    unsigned int piece = BINARY(10010101);
    printf("%u\n", piece);

    return 0;
}
```

in theory, gcc should be able to optimize the calls to strtol away and you don't lose readability.

EDIT: It seems that gcc does NOT optimize the strtol calls away as of now. However, your performance loss should be negligible.

Cheers!

Comment: This seems like a very specific case, gcc 4.7.2 does not optimize this code in `-O3` and still calls `strtol`.

Comment: @lbonn Oh. I really didn't expect that for constant arguments.

Comment: It should be possible but apparently nobody has cared enough to write this optimization. Maybe this use case is considered too rare.

Answer (score 11):

From the gcc manual at: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Alternate-Keywords.html#Alternate-Keywords

> -pedantic and other options cause warnings for many GNU C extensions. You can prevent such warnings within one expression by writing __extension__ before the expression. __extension__ has no effect aside from this.

I just compiled the following block with -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic with gcc-4.8.2, and no warning was printed:

```
static uint8_t shbl[2][9] = {
{ __extension__ 0b11111111,
  __extension__ 0b11111110,
  __extension__ 0b11111100,
  __extension__ 0b11111000,
  __extension__ 0b11110000,
  __extension__ 0b11100000,
  __extension__ 0b11000000,
  __extension__ 0b10000000,
  __extension__ 0b00000000 },
// BLOCK_RIGHT
{ __extension__ 0b11111111,
  __extension__ 0b01111111,
  __extension__ 0b00111111,
  __extension__ 0b00011111,
  __extension__ 0b00001111,
  __extension__ 0b00000111,
  __extension__ 0b00000011,
  __extension__ 0b00000001,
  __extension__ 0b00000000 }
};
```

(Of course this is ugly, and I'll change that to a precompiler macro. But for a test it was acceptable.)