# C++11 variable size POD struct

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, struct, warnings

I am writing a low-lewel data manipulation code in C++ 11 and I want to use an old-known C feature of flexible arrays at the end of the struct ([see some info here](http://d3s.mff.cuni.cz/~holub/c_features.html)).

```
struct variableCell
{
    /**
     * @brief Size in bytes of following data.
     */
    std::uint32_t cellSize;

    /**
     * @brief Data stored in overlay.
     */
    std::uint8_t cellData[];
};
```

Once I use GCC with the paramaters

```
-Wall -pedantic -std=c++11
```

I get this waring

```
xxx.h:xx: warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array 'variableCell' [-Wpedantic]
```

This used to be a perfectly correct feature. Please, do not tell me that my approach is wrong - it is and always has been correct way for low-level data manipulation.

Why the standard changed this and how to disable just this one particular warning?

Thanks

**Edit:**
My apologies, I mistaken the C only feature which turned to be one of the exceptions which does not the C++ include. I will consider using a different approach. But just for my curiosity, which  compilers allows this as a non-standard extension and how to make them accept it without the warning?

Thanks

Comment: The standard didn't change this. This feature was added to C in 1999; C++ was standardised in 1998. As far as standard C++ goes this is not and was never correct.

Comment: You seem to assume the C++ standard is a set of additions to the current C standard. It's not. It is a separate standard defining a separate language, and while that language is almost entirely backwards compatible with C, it is only *almost* so and moreover does not track all "recent" (past 1998) additions to C, at least not instantly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is centered on a false premise.

Comment: @juanchopanza If we closed every question born from a misconception, there would be far less good content on SO and far less programming skill in the world. Correcting false premises is part of answering a question. Please show me which part of the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) disqualifies questions based on false premises.

Comment: @delnan I am not suggesting all questions based on false premises should be closed, but some have very little merit, and are unlikely to result in good answers. I think this is one of those, but will be happy to remove my close vote if proved otherwise.

Comment: sorry about this, but I cannot understand why you downgraded my reply, when it basically says what you after realized in your Edit line :(

Comment: @Marco Pagliaricci, I did no down-vote, someone else did. I am glad for any constructive answer and yours definitively qualifies. At least I can upvote you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As reference [Incompatibilities Between ISO C and ISO C++](http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm#C99-fam) states in *Flexible array members* section:

> C++ does not support flexible array members.
>
> (This feature might be provided as an extension by some C++ compilers, but would probably be valid only for POD structure types.)

[gcc does support this as an extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) as well as [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#intentionally-unsupported-gcc-extensions). Apparently this also works in [Visual Studio - see it live](http://rextester.com/KUE98822) if you don't use `/Za` which I can find any documentation on besides this [post by Stephan T. Lavavej](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2007/08/10/the-future-of-the-c-language.aspx).

I don't think there is a portable way to silence the warning, but something like [Partially disable pedantic warnings in gcc within source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304255/partially-disable-pedantic-warnings-in-gcc-within-source) should work for `gcc`.

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate it with c++ with a custom operator new

```
struct VariableCell {
    VariableCell( std::uint32_t sz ) : cellSize(sz) {}

    std::uint8_t* data() { return reinterpret_cast<std::uint8_t*>(this+1); }

    static void* operator new(std::size_t sz, std::uint32_t dataSz) {
        return ::operator new(sz+dataSz);
    }
private:
    std::uint32_t cellSize;
};

std::unique_ptr<VariableCell> CreateVariableCell( std::uint32_t size ) {
    return std::unique_ptr<VariableCell>{ new (size) VariableCell{size} };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check which standards, C++11 still disallows 0-length arrays (§8.3.4/1), and also C99 (§6.7.5.2/1). It seems they're a C only feature, but I'd rather say an old C hack. Are you sure you can't find a better solution for that?